# How transfer Phonegap projects from a PC to another

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, export

In a few more days I'm getting a new development PC, so my question is how to get my current Phonegap Android Apps (created with Eclipse) over to the new PC? I'm using Phonegap version 3.2.0.

Should I create new projects and just copy paste the files and assets? What about Phonegap version differences? Update Phonegap or Apps Phonegap version just prior the transfer so both old and new PC Phonegap version is the same? How to export from Eclipse?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can directly copy paste the entire folder in Eclipse you can open by clicking on "Android project from exiting code" but make sure you have the same adt plugin and Sdk version installed on your new machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally based on your phonegap version which currently used. and on architecture of app.

How many plugins used and all. Please look into this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html

If your structure is common like no plugins and only www folder then just create new project with CLI and replace your www folder but be sure that use cordova.js be latest one.

Hope this will help.